# Make new gmail email not be grabbed by pop3

Tags: email, gmail, pop3

This seems like a fairly obvious thing but I can't figure out how to do it and am hoping one of your geniuses can help me out!

We have a Gmail email account and then a ticket system that checks that account and sends an auto-reply to the sender saying that the email was received. This is checked via POP3 but can also be done via IMAP if necessary.

What I want is this: For certain messages, I'd like to file them immediately in Gmail and have them go to a special folder and have them NOT be checked by the ticket system. That's all.

I tried creating a filter in Gmail to move them, skip the inbox, mark as read, all of that. They still get picked up by the ticket system.

I thought POP3 only checked the INBOX on any server, so I expected that if I skipped the inbox then it would not be accessible. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Please let me know if there are any tricks I can do.

Thank you so much!

Ben

Comment: I guess this isn't doable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are running into is that when connecting to GMail via POP3, you are actually accessing the "All Mails" folder and not the Inbox, so filtering the messages does not remove them from the list presented to your client via POP3.

Switching to IMAP should solve this problem, however, since you'd be able to open whatever folder you wanted.